# regex : does not begin by "pattern"

Tags: regex, grep

I have a lot of lines in my LIST file and want to list only lines whose name does not start by (or contains) "git".

So far I have :

```
cat LIST | grep ^[^g]
```

but I would like something like :

```
#not starting by "git"
cat LIST | grep ^[^(git)]
#not containing "git"
cat LIST | grep .*[^(git)].*
```

but it is not correct. What regex should I use ?

Answer (score 26):

Using `grep` in this case with `-P` option, which Interprets the PATTERN as a Perl regular expression

```
grep -P '^(?:(?!git).)*$' LIST
```

Regular expression explanation:

```
^             the beginning of the string
 (?:          group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
   (?!        look ahead to see if there is not:
     git      'git'
   )          end of look-ahead
   .          any character except \n
 )*           end of grouping
$             before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Using the `find` command

```
find . \! -iname "git*"
```

Comment: Not sure how/if the expression would be optimzed internally, but I wouldn't use the quantifier `+` on the outer group. Considering it won't capture its match I'd simply remove it alltogether for a more simple/readable expression.

Comment: This expression will match anything from start to end of a line that does not start with `git`

Comment: Your first command is what I am looking for :)
However I do not understand what (?!git) does ?

Comment: It is a negative look ahead assertion, see updated edit.

Answer (score 18):

Since the OP is looking for a general regex and not specially for grep, this is the general regex for lines not starting with "git".

`^(?!git).*`

Breakdown:

`^` beginning of line

`(?!git)` not followed by 'git'

`.*` followed by 0 or more characters

Answer (score 7):

If you want to simply list all lines that don't contain git try this

```
 cat LIST | grep -v git
```

Comment: In that specific case, it does work. Thanks. But I would have preferred the use of regular expressions since it can be used in much more cases (for exemple a perl script parsing a user input).

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2219830/981380) on SO has what you need.

Comment: Almost. I try to match what does NOT contain the string. Without using "-v" option from grep if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to the accepted answer that will work in more situations and a broader swath of engines (moves . to outside second closing parenthesis):

```
^(?:(?!git)).*$
```

This example finds any lines that begin with anything except git or ls:

```
^(?:(?!git|ls)).*$
```

Comment: The non-capture group is useless. `^(?!git).*$` does the same.

Comment: The non-capture group is not necessary, but it is useful. There is [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512530/379841) in a capturing group, that can [negatively impact performance](https://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/capturing-vs-non-capturing-groups): “The performance hit may be tiny, especially when working with small strings, but it's there.” Also, as Levithan describes, non-capturing groups conveniently do not clutter up backreferences and reduce maintenance burden, so developers do not have to worry about references.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanna find the lines "not starting with git", you could also use:

```
^[^git].*
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes here. "^" inside cornered brackets e.g. [^not], simply means "not". I've tested this for Java Regex and it works!

Comment: I do not think it is tested enough: your pattern will match everything that does not begin by "g", "i" OR "t". For example it will not match "iran" because it starts with "i". The question was to just ignore what began by "git".

Comment: I see your point. I actually used it to filter out a single char at the end of the String .*[^s], but I didn't know multiple chars like above means "OR". Thanks for your input.